# Ajax Submitting form Twice

Tags: ajax

I have a form in a modal window that allows a user to resend a confirmation email. When the form is submitted, the confirmation email is sent twice, instead of once. Everything else is working exactly as it should.

Form is pretty standard:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ReMailf" name="ReMailf" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
<fieldset>
<div class="row">
<p>You may enter a different email than your original if you wish. However, the original email will remain as the main contact on your application.</p>
<label class="desc" for="prim_email"> Email </label>
<input id="prim_email" name="prim_email" type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $tE['prim_email']; ?>" data-error="Please Enter A Valid Email Address" required/>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<input id="submitForm" name="submitForm" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Resend Conformation "/>
<input name="uniqid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tE['unqID']; ?>"/>
<input name="ReMAIL" type="hidden" value="ReMAIL"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

… and here's the handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ReMailf").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        // var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: '_remail.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#myModal .modal-header .modal-title').html("YOUR EMAIL HAS BEEN RESENT");
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
                // $("#ReMailf").remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
        $("#ReMailf").submit();
    });

});
```

I've read a number of other post about this, and tried some of the suggestions, but nothing is working. It either doesn't submit at all, or submits twice.
This is the only form on the page...

Suggestions please?

Comment: `$("#submitForm").on('click'` isn't necessary. The submit button IS a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using a button or submit to trigger the ajax event. Use this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#ReMailf").on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //add this line
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            // var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                  url: '_remail.php',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: postData,
                  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#myModal .modal-header .modal-title').html("YOUR EMAIL HAS BEEN RESENT");
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
                    // $("#ReMailf").remove();
                  },
                  error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                    console.log(status + ": " + error);
                  }
```

or you can just use a simple form with action and method. It will do the job

Comment: This took care of the issue. Thanks very much!